# Evaluating a string using recursion

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns True is the string passed in is `'1'`(valid) or `'1*'`(valid) or in the form of `'(' + valid + '|' + valid + ')'` (valid). What I mean by the last part is for example:

`(1|1)` <- since its in the form of `'(' + valid + '|' + valid + ')'` and `'1'` is valid.
`((1|1)|1)` <- since its in the form of `'(' + valid + '|' + valid + ')'` and `(1|1)` is valid and so is '1'

`((1|(1|1))|1)` <- since its in the form of `'(' + valid + '|' + valid + ')'` and `(1|(1|1))` is valid and so is `'1'`

**My plan:**

- 1.) if the string passed in is '1', return True (Base Case)
- 2.) if the string passed in is '1'+'*', return True
- 3.) Else, if the string passed in begins with a '(' and ends with ')'
     look at the contents inside of the bracket and find the '|' symbol
     that's not inside of another bracket. Once it is found run the function again
     on the string on the left of the found symbol, and also run the function again
     on the string on the right of the found symbol. If both are True then the string
     is True (Recursive Step)
- 4.) Return False if anything else is passed in.

**My code based on my plan:**

```
def check(s):
    if s == '1':
        return True
    elif s == '1'+'*':
        return True
    else:
        if s.startswith('(') and s.endswith(')'):
            #TO-DO
            pass
    return False
```

**Some examples:**

```
check('((1|1)|1)')
True
check('((1|1*)|1)')
True
check('(1|1)')
True
check('1')
True
check('1*')
True
check('((1|(1|1))|1)')
True
check('((1|(1|1))|((1|(1|1))|1))')
True
check('*1')
False
check('2')
False
check('((1|(1|1));1)')
False
```

I spent 3 days on this and still couldn't figure out how to do the recursive step so I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I can't figure out how to find the `'*'` symbol that is not within another set of brackets. I think if I'am able to find that `'*'` symbol than I can do the rest myself.

I'm sure that we can do this using the re module but let's just pretend we can't use that.

Comment: So is `(1||1|)` valid? Because accroding to your description it is, but it seems strange. Is `(1|)` really valid?

Comment: That seems strange as well, I'll go ahead an introduce a new symbol so that there's not something like || which is pretty confusing.

Comment: Yes, please. That is the only thing that makes parsing awkward here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing small grammars like this, I would suggest you to simplify them manually to a point where you can apply a non-backtracking [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). The grammar you gave is:

```
valid ::= "1*" | "1" | "(" valid "|" valid ")"
```

so it is already non-left-recursive and ready to go, you just have to prefer `1*` over `1`. I suggest your parser functions to have type `string -> (bool, string)`, where the `bool` indicates whether the parsing was successful and the second component is the unparsed rest of the string. Instead of the `bool`, you can also return an internal representation (AST) of the parsed string.

As an example, here is a parser for the `valid` production:

```
def valid(s):
    if s.startswith('1*'):
        return True, s[2:]
    if s.startswith('1'):
        return True, s[1:]
    if s.startswith('('):
        success, rest = valid(s[1:])
        if not success or not rest.startswith('|'): return False, s
        success, rest = valid(rest[1:])
        if not success or not rest.startswith(')'): return False, s
        return True, rest[1:]
    return False, s

def check(s):
    return valid(s) == (True, '')
```

Comment: This fails on "1|" and "(1|1) is given as an example of a string that should pass.

Comment: @GraemeStuart: Yes, but then again OP probably underspecified the grammar. Since I don't know all the special cases (is '(1||1||1)` allowed?) I can only give an example to maybe point OP into the right direction

Comment: @GraemeStuart: I meant `(1)` instead of `(1|1)`